# Help with understanding the expectation of error terms in linear regression

Tags: probability, statistics

While reading a proof on residuals in linear regression, I came across a step that I lacked the understanding of. Can you please explain why the expectation of the function $(\mathcal{E}_i-\bar{\mathcal{E}})^2$ is $\frac{n-1}{n}\sigma^2$?

$E(\mathcal{E}_i-\bar{\mathcal{E}})^2 = \frac{n-1}{n}\sigma^2$

where $y_i = \beta_0 + \beta_1x_i + \mathcal{E}_i$ for $i = 1,2,...,n$

After doing some reading, I understood that $E(\mathcal{E}_i-\bar{\mathcal{E}})^2$ is nothing but variance of $\mathcal{E}_i$ i.e., Var($\mathcal{E}_i$). It is given that Var($\mathcal{E}_i$) is $\sigma^2$. However, I don't understand from where the term $\frac{n-1}{n}$ came from. Any pointers?

Thank you!

Comment: Are you talking about linear regression?

Comment: yes, correct, linear regression.

Comment: How is your error term defined? And check your previous questions if you have marked answers as accepted

Comment: All I see is $E(\epsilon_i) = 0$ and Var$(\epsilon_i)=\sigma^2$ and all $\epsilon_i$'s are independent

Comment: But how is $\epsilon_i$ is defined, maybe $\epsilon_i=y_i-ax_i-b$?

Comment: thanks. i am looking into it. i have a notation mistake in my question. i overlooked uppercase and lowercase epsilons. how can i tell the editor to use uppercase vs lowercase?

Comment: For instance, the formula for $\epsilon_i$ is \epsilon_i and for $x^k$ is x^k

Comment: i have updated my question now. thanks.